# IIS Application Request Routing ignore certificate

Tags: iis, proxy, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I use one of development sites as URL rewrite to access other sites.

Unfortunately one of the sites has a certificate error because we access it under VPN under different IP.

IIS says that the link I'm trying to get thru rewrite has "HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway A security error occurred" with code "Error Code 0x80072f8f" from "Handler ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler"

I need to set up ARR in such a way that this error is ignored and Rewrite is done successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ARR registry options described here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/arr-support-added-for-winhttpoptionsecurityflags

Comment: had to also make a gzip fix for url rewrite, but this helped! Thanks!